# Tracking model/image disappears with autofocus enabled

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am using `Ar Core Augmented Images` to track and load/display and then capture the image. It was working with the one plus phone I had. But now I got a new phone Moto g6. With this phone, the camera preview is not focusing. The image is blurred.

So I used the following to enable autofocus

```
//Create the config
arConfig = new Config(arSession);

//Check if the configuration is set to fixed
if (arConfig.getFocusMode() == Config.FocusMode.FIXED) {
    arConfig.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
}

//Sceneform requires that the ARCore session is configured to the UpdateMode LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE.
//This is probably not required for just auto focus. I was updating the camera configuration as well
arConfig.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);

//Reconfigure the session
arSession.configure(arConfig);

//Setup the session with ARSceneView
arFragment.getArSceneView().setupSession(arSession);
```

It works fine it does autofocus the and I get the desired result. The issue is I can't scan the image/marker when autofocus is enabled. So I am enabling autofocus once the scanning is complete but as soon as I enable autofocus tracking is lost and loaded model/image disappears.

Is there any way I can use autofocus without losing the loaded model/image

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet has proved to be working (you can enable/disable `autofocus mode` thru `ARCore Session Config`):

```
Session session = new Session(context);
Config configuration = new Config(session);

if (enableAutoFocus) {
    configuration.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
} else {
    configuration.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.FIXED);
}
session.configure(configuration);
```

> **But**! Here's an important info:
>
> **Google [confirms](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/01/29/google-confirms-autofocus-not-working-in-arcore-for-several-lg-phones/) that `autofocus isn't working` in ARCore** for these `LG phones`:

- G7 Fit
- G7 One
- G7 ThinQ
- V30
- V30+
- V30+ JOJO
- LG Signature Edition 2017
- V35 ThinQ
- LG Signature Edition 2018
- V40

> This issue with autofocus might cause problems with tracking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm already doing what you suggested. I am able to autofocus. I am just stating that with Motorola phone I am having an issue with tracking with autofocus/ keeping model on the screen when switched to autofocus

Comment: Google just recently added an ARCore support for the Motorola One, Motorola One Power, and Nokia 8.1 phones. Are you using ARCore 1.8 version?

Comment: I'm using Motorola G6 and yes I'm using 1.8.0 version